# Spring MVC - How to set return media type when handling HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring 3.2 MVC REST service, which implements error handling by extending `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`. This handles the [standard Spring exceptions](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-rest-spring-mvc-exceptions), and will respond with the appropriate HTTP status and custom "Error" ResponseEntity object in XML or JSON as requested by the client. This works great for all of the standard exceptions except `HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException`.

The problem I have with this exception is that the reason its thrown in the first place is because the response media type (application/xml, application/json, etc.) could not be determined from the request. If I try to return an "Error" ResponseEntity object for this exception it will fail because the response media type couldn't be determined (which is why this exception is being handled in the first place)...and basically get another `HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException` thrown from my ExceptionHandler.

I need to figure out a way when handling `HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException` to specify a valid response media type, so the ResponseEntity makes it to the client. Since requested media type can't be determined, this would probably just be the default for my service (application/xml)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found same problem in my development, to so solve this issue you need specify in the reponsebody of your error message present in your all method annoted `@ExceptionHandler` of your `controllerAdvicer` the `contentType`:

for exemple: your receive header `Accept: application/pdf` but your application produce `application/json`.

class `GlobalExceptionHandler`  annoted with `@ControllerAdvice` to manage specific body response:

```
    package com.obs.sfu.exception;

import javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException;

import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException;
import org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException;
import org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.NoHandlerFoundException;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException;

@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    private static final String SIZE_MUST_BE_FROM_1_TO_15_CHARACTERS = "Size must be from 1 to 15 characters";
    private static final int CODE_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR = 1;
    private static final String MESSAGE_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR = "Internal error";
    private static final String DESCRIPTION_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR = "Generic failure message";

    private static final int CODE_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE = 5;
    private static final String MESSAGE_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE = "The service is temporarily unavailable";
    private static final String DESCRIPTION_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE = "The service can not handle the call.";

    private static final int CODE_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE = 68;
    private static final String MESSAGE_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE = "Unsupported Media Type";
    private static final String DESCRIPTION_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE = "The format of the posted body is not supported by the endpoint.";

    private static final int CODE_NOT_FOUND = 60;
    private static final String MESSAGE_NOT_FOUND = "Resource not found";
    private static final String DESCRIPTION_NOT_FOUND = "The Requested URI or the requested resource does not exist.";

    private static final int CODE_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED = 61;
    private static final String MESSAGE_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED = "Method not allowed";
    private static final String DESCRIPTION_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED = "The URI does not support the requested method. The available methods should be set in the response header 'Allow'";

    private static final int CODE_NOT_ACCEPTABLE = 62;
    private static final String MESSAGE_NOT_ACCEPTABLE = "Not acceptable";
    private static final String DESCRIPTION_NOT_ACCEPTABLE = "The Accept incoming header does not match any available content-type.";

    private static final int CODE_CONSTRAINT_VIOLATION_FIELD = 20;
    private static final String MESSAGE_INVALID_BODY_FIELD = "Invalid Via field";

    private static final String HEADER_ALLOW = "Allow";
    private static final String HEADER_ALLOW_VALUE = "GET, OPTIONS";

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleNoHandlerFoundException(NoHandlerFoundException ex, HttpHeaders headers,
            HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(request.getContextPath(), MESSAGE_NOT_FOUND, DESCRIPTION_NOT_FOUND,
                CODE_NOT_FOUND);
        return ResponseEntity.status(status).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(errorDetails);
    }

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException ex,
            HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(request.getContextPath(), MESSAGE_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED,
                DESCRIPTION_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED, CODE_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.set(HEADER_ALLOW, HEADER_ALLOW_VALUE);
        return ResponseEntity.status(status).headers(responseHeaders).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(errorDetails);
    }

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMediaTypeNotSupported(HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException ex,
            HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(request.getContextPath(), MESSAGE_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE,
                DESCRIPTION_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE, CODE_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE);
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.set("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        return ResponseEntity.status(status).headers(responseHeaders).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(errorDetails);
    }

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMediaTypeNotAcceptable(HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException ex,
            HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(request.getContextPath(), MESSAGE_NOT_ACCEPTABLE,
                DESCRIPTION_NOT_ACCEPTABLE, CODE_NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
        return ResponseEntity.status(status).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(errorDetails);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleConstraintViolation(ConstraintViolationException ex, WebRequest request) {
        ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(request.getContextPath(), MESSAGE_INVALID_BODY_FIELD,
                SIZE_MUST_BE_FROM_1_TO_15_CHARACTERS, CODE_CONSTRAINT_VIOLATION_FIELD);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(errorDetails);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(SoapFaultClientException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleSoapFaultClient(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(request.getContextPath(), MESSAGE_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE,
                DESCRIPTION_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE, CODE_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(errorDetails);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleGlobalException(Exception ex, WebRequest request) {
        ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(request.getContextPath(), MESSAGE_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                DESCRIPTION_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, CODE_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(errorDetails);
    }
}
```

file `application.properties` need these properties to manage `NoHandlerFoundException` (`throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound`):

```
spring:
  mvc: 
    throw-exception-if-no-handler-found: true
    static-path-pattern: /swagger* # to available swagger-ui.html
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** this answer is pretty useless, see comment below. Sorry.

As in this case the communication is pretty messed up anyway, maybe it is enough to set the status code to `400 - Bad Request` and hope the client does not really expect a machine readable answer in a format that is not known to the server anyway. If a response body is send, maybe use `Content-Type: text/plain` - that will be of no use for the client, but maybe the person debugging the situation ;) Well, or whatever fits your mood.

*Update:* a better fitting solution might be to use the method explained in the manual; at: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-customer-servlet-container-error-page however I have to admit I did not really try if that works.

Comment: It returns the `406 - Not Acceptable` like it's supposed to in this case, but the problem is I don't seem to have any control over the body or Content-Type. I always get the default HTML Tomcat error page. I've tried setting the Content-Type header in the response, but it gets wiped out (along with the body) during message converter processing.

Comment: Narf, I thougth tomcat does not do that, as we are already in the error handling phase. Me wrong. On the page you linked to it talks in Cp 17.11.5 about setting up a custom error page, where one can stuff in a `@RequestMapping(value="/error", produces="application/json")` in the error controller, maybe that does the trick.